# What is the intersection of an array type and a regular object type?

Tags: typescript

I have this simple snippet in TypeScript 5.1.3 where I try to figure out what an object of type `unknown[] & A` would look like.

```js
interface A {
    text: string
}

type AB = unknown[] & A

let a: AB = [{text: "ASDF"}]

console.log(a)
```

As it stands, I'm getting an error saying

```
Type '{ text: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'AB'.
  Property 'text' is missing in type '{ text: string; }[]' but required in type 'A'.(2322)
```

Does anyone know what an object of this type is supposed to look like?

Comment: Is your question purely about what `unknown[] & A` is?

Comment: It is an Array of `unknown` elements, that is also assignable to `A`. In this case, that means that it is an Array with the extra property `text`.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wyjedw) make it clear?  It's an array with an extra property set on it.  If that fully addresses the question I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Actually yes, I'm supposed to add the text field to the array itself. `Object.assign` is one way, or I guess I could make a class that extends `Array` and add that field over there. And yes, I wanted to know what `unknown[] & A` would look like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to know what value satisfies `AB` as defined below:

```js
interface A {
    text: string
}

type AB = unknown[] & A;
```

First of all, `unknown[]` represents an array of elements of unknown type. `A` represents an object with the property `text` of type `string`.

`AB` is created by [intersecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) these types.
This creates a new type that is assignable to both of the intersected types: it is the intersection of the sets of values that satisfy those types.
**Therefore, the value that satisfies this type is an array with the extra property `text` of type `string`.**

This can be created in a type-safe way like follows:

```js
interface A {
  text: string
}

type AB = unknown[] & A

const arr = [1, 2, 3]

const result: AB = Object.assign(arr, { text: "Some text" })
```

[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/W47Pem)

On a side note...
If you want to know how to create a type that has the "target" type intersected with the *element* type of the array, you can use the following [generic type](https://www.totaltypescript.com/mental-model-for-typescript-generics). It takes an array type and produces a new array type with the element type intersected with a given target type.
I.e., you can use it to turn `{ name: string }[]` and `{ text: string }` into `{ name: string; text: string}[]`.

```js
interface A {
  text: string
}

type MyArray = { name: string }[]

type IntersectArrayElements<A, T> = A extends (infer Element)[]
  ? (Element & T)[]
  : never

type IntersectedArray = IntersectArrayElements<MyArray, A>
//   ^? ({ name: string; } & A)[]
//    = { name: string; text: string; }[]
```

[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N5kPZW)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer lies in the fact that `A` needs to not constrain fields from `unknown[]`. The `text` field isn't in the TypeScript array, so it can't really be intersected.

As it stands, no object can be of type `AB`, but if A were to extend the empty object `{}` or be another type of array (e.g. `type A = {text: string}[]`) this would work fine.

Comment: An object can. Create an Array and add a `text` property.